# Error while creating view in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am new for SQL Server view creation.

In my project there is a requirement to create the view (View_SalesOrder) in sql server which should be exactly same as like another view called View_Quotation.

It should just replace the word 'Quotation' to 'SalesOrder'.

When I did so it creates the view but with the following error message

```js
Msg 15097, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addextendedproperty, Line 16
The size associated with an extended property cannot be more than 7,500 bytes.
```

My View_SalesOrder is

```js
USE [MehtechDb]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[View_SalesOrder]    Script Date: 12/19/2014 12:35:48 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create VIEW [dbo].[View_SalesOrder]
AS
SELECT     dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Refno, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.RefNoDate, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Authorised, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientCompanyName, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientBranch, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientPerson, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.TypeOfEnquiry, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.EnquiryDate, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.DueDate, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Delivery, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.PF, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Tax, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Payment, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Validity, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Frieght, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.CompanyNote, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Note, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Status, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.QuoteSentThro, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.CliSno, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Description, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Size, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Qty, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Unitprice, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Discount, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Totalprice, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Designation, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line1, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line2, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line3, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line4, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.City, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.State, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.District, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Country, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.PostalCode, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Phone, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Mobile, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Pro_ItemCode as Email, dbo.tbl_UserMaster.Designation AS Designation1, dbo.tbl_UserMaster.ContactNo, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OfficeName, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Line1 AS OCLine1, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Line2 AS OCLine2, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Line3 AS OCLine3, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.District AS OCDistrict, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.City AS OCCity, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.PostalCode AS OCPostalCode, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.PhoneNo AS OCPhoneNo, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.FaxNo AS OCFaxNo, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Email AS OCEmail, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Website AS OCWebsite, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.TinNo AS OCTinNo, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Cstno AS OCCstno, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.AreaCode AS OCAreaCode, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.RefRevNo, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.EnquiryRefNo as OtherRefNo, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientEnqDt, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientDueDt, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.KeyPerson, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.CompanyName, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Line1 AS OCNewLine1, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Line2 AS OCNewLine2, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Line3 AS OCNewLine3, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.District AS OCNewDistrict, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.City AS OCNewCity, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.PostalCode AS OCNewPostalCode, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.PhoneNo AS OCNewPhoneNo, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Email AS OCNewEmail, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Availability, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Currency, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.ClientCode, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.ID, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Subject as ProjectName ,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Octrai,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ExciseDuty,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.GuranteeWaranty,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OtherLabel,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OtherText
FROM         dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Refno = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.RefNo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Refno = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Refno AND 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.RefNo = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Refno LEFT JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_UserMaster ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Authorised = dbo.tbl_UserMaster.UserFullName ON 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.OfficeName = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.CompanyNote LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail AS tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1 ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OfficeName = tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.OfficeName

GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[64] 4[12] 2[11] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "tbl_OurCompanyDetail"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 8
               Left = 1133
               Bottom = 342
               Right = 1294
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "tbl_SalesOrderHeader"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 421
               Right = 226
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "tbl_SalesOrderDetails"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 23
               Left = 313
               Bottom = 350
               Right = 462
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 0
               Left = 544
               Bottom = 367
               Right = 710
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "tbl_UserMaster"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 0
               Left = 751
               Bottom = 304
               Right = 915
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 69
               Left = 922
               Bottom = 411
               Right = 1077
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 2
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
      Begin ColumnWidths =' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'View_SalesOrder'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane2', @value=N' 73
         Width = 284
         Width = 3150
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 11
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 900
         Table = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'View_SalesOrder'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value=2 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'View_SalesOrder'
GO
```

I searched for the solution everywhere but not found the exact one.

I read about the extended property as well but in my case am not getting exactly how to solve it.

If anyone has any idea please reply as early as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message is fairly self explanatory - you've exceeded the maximum number of bytes for one of the extended properties. - Specifically its the one named: MS_DiagramPane1

Just did a quick test - and that property has 3752 characters, which assuming UNICODE (or similar) encoding would come to 7504 bytes.

This means you are only marginally over the maximum number of bytes for that extended property. If you just removed a few whitespace characters for example it would be fine (I've quickly tested this!)

Comment: As I hv mentioned earlier m new in making the views in sql server. Concept of extended property is totally new for me. So can u plz elaborate how you have tested it. I tried to execute only sys.sp_addextendedproperty block but issue is one n the same.

Comment: @Mandy I just created a random view (not with your table) - and then ran the first sp_addextendedproperty statement. Then I removed a few spaces from the text block specified by `@value = N'....  '` (just reduced the indent of some of the XML inside this block a bit) After this it ran without an error. The Extended property only associates some text with the view definition - it doesn't affect how the view works.

Answer (score 0):

The extended property is optional. If you remove the everything after the GO, the view will still be created and will have no impact on your application...

```
create VIEW [dbo].[View_SalesOrder]
AS
SELECT     dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Refno, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.RefNoDate, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Authorised, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientCompanyName, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientBranch, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientPerson, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.TypeOfEnquiry, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.EnquiryDate, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.DueDate, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Delivery, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.PF, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Tax, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Payment, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Validity, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Frieght, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.CompanyNote, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Note, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Status, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.QuoteSentThro, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.CliSno, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Description, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Size, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Qty, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Unitprice, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Discount, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Totalprice, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Designation, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line1, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line2, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line3, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Line4, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.City, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.State, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.District, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Country, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.PostalCode, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Phone, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Mobile, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Pro_ItemCode as Email, dbo.tbl_UserMaster.Designation AS Designation1, dbo.tbl_UserMaster.ContactNo, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OfficeName, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Line1 AS OCLine1, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Line2 AS OCLine2, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Line3 AS OCLine3, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.District AS OCDistrict, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.City AS OCCity, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.PostalCode AS OCPostalCode, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.PhoneNo AS OCPhoneNo, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.FaxNo AS OCFaxNo, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Email AS OCEmail, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Website AS OCWebsite, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.TinNo AS OCTinNo, 
                      tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.Cstno AS OCCstno, tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.AreaCode AS OCAreaCode, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.RefRevNo, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.EnquiryRefNo as OtherRefNo, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientEnqDt, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ClientDueDt, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.KeyPerson, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.CompanyName, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Line1 AS OCNewLine1, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Line2 AS OCNewLine2, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Line3 AS OCNewLine3, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.District AS OCNewDistrict, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.City AS OCNewCity, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.PostalCode AS OCNewPostalCode, dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.PhoneNo AS OCNewPhoneNo, 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.Email AS OCNewEmail, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.Availability, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Currency, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.ClientCode, 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.ID, dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Subject as ProjectName ,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Octrai,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.ExciseDuty,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.GuranteeWaranty,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OtherLabel,tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OtherText
FROM         dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Refno = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.RefNo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Refno = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Refno AND 
                      dbo.tbl_SalesOrderDetails.RefNo = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderClientAddress.Refno LEFT JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_UserMaster ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.Authorised = dbo.tbl_UserMaster.UserFullName ON 
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail.OfficeName = dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.CompanyNote LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_OurCompanyDetail AS tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1 ON dbo.tbl_SalesOrderHeader.OfficeName = tbl_OurCompanyDetail_1.OfficeName

GO
```